# How do I get the result of a Select SQL statement in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I want to be able to use SQL to retrieve Data from a table and display to the immediate window in Access.

I am new to VBA and I can't seem to find the way of doing it

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Dim result As Variant

strSQL = "SELECT x, from y WHERE z;"

Set cdb = CurrentDb

Debug.Print strSQL

result = Call cdb.Execute(strSQL)

Debug.Print result
```

Comment: `Execute` is not the right way to do this. You need to use a `Recordset` object to have it return a set of data. Also, remove the comma after `x` in your select statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243789(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: `Execute` returns a `Recordset` object, so you need to `Set results = connection.Execute(sql)`, and then iterate the returned records. Plenty of help and examples readily available in thousands of places on this site. Did you try *searching*?

Comment: Not Execute(sql), `Dim result AS DAO.Recordset` then `Set result = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print value of field from only first record.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim result As DAO.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT x FROM y WHERE z;"
Set result = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
Debug.Print result!x
```

If you want to print a value from each record, use a loop structure to move to each record like:

```
Do While Not result.EOF
    Debug.Print result!x
    result.MoveNext
Loop
```

Review this site http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html - look at the section 'Examples by Library' about halfway down.

Answer (score 2):

To produce the result with just one line (assuming only one record is going to be returned), you can use:

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT x FROM y WHERE z").Fields(0).Value
```

You can also use the DLookUp function, which is not SQL but you will recognise the parts:

```
Debug.Print DLookUp("x", "y", "z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using *With* syntax  ..

```
Dim Cnt as Long
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE X=2")
    If Not .EOF Then
        Cnt = .Fields(0).Value
    End If
End With
```